# Extract (maybe oblique) slice from a volume

Tags: matrices, volume

I have a three-dimensional matrix (representing a volume) with integer values in it (grey values). I now want to put a (maybe oblique) plane inside the volume and extract the values that project onto that plane.

In medical terms, it is called a Multiplanar Reformation (MPR) and looks like this:

[image]

Can you describe a good algorithm for doing that or lead me to some resources?